# ASP.NET Core 3.1 run on IIS .NET CLR v4.0 and integrated managed must be a pool for each APP?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-3.1

I run multiple asp.net core 3.1 app run windows IIS, system will show error `HTTP Error 500.35 - ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process`
[image]

It's ok for asp.net mvc, it can run multiple app in same pool.

Edit:

I've read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0#50035-ancm-multiple-in-process-applications-in-same-process

> 500.35 ANCM Multiple In-Process Applications in same Process
> The worker process can't run multiple in-process apps in the same process.
> To fix this error, run apps in separate IIS application pools.

It looks like it must be a pool for each APP...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the asp.net core [In-process hosting model article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.0#in-process-hosting-model) shows:

> Sharing an app pool among apps isn't supported. Use one app pool per app.

That means we should only use one app pool per asp.net core application.